# Javascript For...In syntax issue?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, iterator, for-in-loop

The search function in the following code is not working and I believe it has something to do with the For...In loop but I am new to JS and unsure why:

```
var friends = {
bill: {
    firstName: "bill",
    lastName: "smith",
    number: 1,
    address: ["1"]
},
steve: {
    firstName: "steve",
    lastName: "smith",
    number: 2,
    address: ["2"]
}
};

var list = function(list) {
for(var item in list) {
    console.log(item);
}
};

var search = function(name) {

for(var friend in friends) {
    if(friend.firstName === name) {
        console.log(friend);
        return friend;
    }
}
};

search("steve");
```

Comment: I recommend to refer to the MDN documentation if you are unsure about a certain function or construct: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in.

Answer (score 2):

The `for in` loop iterates over *keys*, not values.

`friend` is a string holding the name of each property.
To get the value, use `friends[friend]`.

Answer (score 0):

Great documentation of the for..in loop can be found on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Where `variable` is assigned through each iteration to "a different property **name**".

You also may not need to loop through each friend. What if you changed your search function to use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) on the object:

```
var search = function(name) {
    if(friends.hasOwnProperty(name)){
        return friends[name];
    }
};
```

This would check that you have a property of `name` in the object `friends` and return it. Here's a quick [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/HZsTT/1/).